# Add initialization listener to war from ear

Tags: java, glassfish-3, ear

I have a ear project that has as dependency a war and I need to trigger an action when this application starts. If I could modify the war itself I would add a listener to the `web.xml`, but is not possible for me to modify this project at the moment.

Is it possible to add a listener to the ear project? What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: If you are hain Spring, you could create an ApplicationContextListener that will be called as soon as your spring context is initialized.

Comment: What is the event you are trying to listen? Is that simply application deployed?

Comment: Yes, in others cases I've solved it with a `<listener>` in the `web.xml`. But in this case I cannot modify the war project.